# Sharing File descriptors across processes

Tags: file, shared-memory

I want to setup a shared memory environment for multiple independent processes. In the data structure that I want to share, there are also connection fds which are per process.

I wanted to know if there is a way in which we can share these fds? or use global fds or something similar of the kind?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to share file descriptors on a Unix host. One is by letting a child process inherit them across a `fork`.

The other is sending file descriptors over a Unix domain socket with `sendmsg`; see this example program, function [`send_connection`](http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-hacks/2002-January/000292.html) (archived [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/kragen-hacks@canonical.org/msg00002.html)). Note that the file descriptor might have a different number in the receiving process, so you may have to perform some `dup2` magic to make them come out right in your shared memory.

If you don't do this, the file descriptors in your shared memory region will be just integers.

Comment: Does dup work across processes? That is can a process dup other process' fd (pointing to the same file that it wants to point to) and start using the new fd thereafter?

Comment: @SunandaSharma: no, `dup` clones fds within a single process. What I meant is that you'll have to synchronize the actual numbers that the fds have in the various processes, then use `dup2` to set them to be the same across processes.

Comment: oh okay. Then this setup will not be able to work for me unfortunately. Thanks a lot for your inputs :)

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I had to solve a problem similar to what OP is describing. To this end, I moved to propose a dedicated system call (a very simple one, I might add) to send file descriptors directly to cooperating processes addresses and relying on Posix.1b signal queues as a delivery medium (as an added benefit, such approach is inherently immune to "fd recursion" attack, which plagues all VFS based mechanisms to some degree).

Here's the proposed patch:

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1843084

(presently, the patch only adds the new syscall for x86/x86_64 architecture, but wiring it up to other architectures is trivial, there are no platform depended features utilized).

A theory of operation goes like following. Both sender and receiver need to agree on one or more signal numbers to use for descriptor passing. Those must be Posix.1b signals, which guarantee reliable delivery, thus `SIGRTMIN` offset. Also, smaller signal numbers have higher delivery priority, in case priority management is required:

```
int signo_to_use = SIGRTMIN + my_sig_off;
```

Then, originating process invokes a system call:

```
int err = sendfd(peer_pid, signo_to_use, fd_to_send);
```

That's it, nothing else is necessary on the sender's side. Obviously, `sendfd()` will only be successful, if the originating process has the right to signal destination process and destination process is not blocking/ignoring the signal.

It must also be noted, that `sendfd()` never blocks; it will return immediately if destination process' signal queue is full. In a well designed application, this will indicate that destination process is in trouble anyway, or there's too much work to do, so new workers shall be spawned/work items dropped. The size of the process' signal queue can be configured using `rlimit()`, same as the number of available file descriptors.

The receiving process may safely ignore the signal (in this case nothing will happen and almost no overhead will be incurred on the kernel side). However, if receiving process wants to get the delivered file descriptor, all it has to to is to collect the signal info using `sigtimedwait()`/`sigwaitinfo()` or a more versatile `signalfd()`:

```
/* First, the receiver needs to specify what it is waiting for: */
sigset_t sig_mask;
sigemptyset(&sig_mask);
sigaddset(&sig_mask, signo_to_use);

siginfo_t sig_info;
/* Then all it needs is to wait for the event: */
sigwaitinfo(&sig_mask, sig_info);
```

After the successful return of the `sigwaitinfo()`, `sig_info.si_int` will contain the new file descriptor, pointing to the same IO object, as file descriptor sent by the originating process. `sig_info.si_pid` will contain the originating process' PID, and `sig_info.si_uid` will contain the originating process' UID. If `sig_info.si_int` is less than zero (represents an invalid file descriptor), `sig_info.si_errno` will contain the `errno` for the actual error encountered during fd duplication process.